# Can I use a variable I got from the player into a text box?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an app in Unity which requires your name and other details. I'm using the legacy Input Field to get the answers from the player which worked, but I can't seem to use the Input in any way other than Debug.Log.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReadInput : MonoBehaviour
{

    private string input;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void ReadStringInput(string s)
    {
        input = s;
        Debug.Log(input);
    }
}
```

I used this simple script to get the input but I have no clue how to actually use it in the game. It want it to say, for example, Welcome,(Person's Name/Input) outside of the log and actually into a text object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click in the hierarchy, under UI you can add a text object. I like to use a free package called Text Mesh Pro, which you can get in the asset store, but you don't need to.
Once you've made your text object, it should appear as a child of a gameobject called the Canvas. The text object should have a text field that you can access from script.

```
Text mytext;

public void UpdateMyText(string s)
{
    mytext.text = s;
}
```

[Here's the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html)

Just drag the text object into the script's mytext field in the inspector, and call that function when you want to update your text.